# Unit testing express route callback - mock res object

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, express, mocha.js

I'm struggling to understand how to unit test a simple express get request which renders a html file.

In my setup when i'm receiving an error about view engine not being set, when i run my code.

All I want to do is simply check if the 'res.render' function has been called and mock this so it doesn't actually do what it supposed to do.

route.js

```
module.exports = function(router) {

    router.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
        console.log("Hi");
        res.render('test/test', { current: "current"});
    });
};
```

test.js

```
const request = require('supertest');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const routes = require('../../routes/route')(app);
describe('My routes', function () {

    before(function() {
        return this.spy = sinon.spy(app, 'render');
    });

    after(function() {
        return this.spy.restore();
    });

    it('should render to /test', function(done) {

        var res = { render: sinon.spy() };

        request(app)
            .get('/test')
            .expect(200, done)
    });
});
```

its failing on the res.render('test/test') line, i dont acutally want this line to execute i want to mock it somehow?

I think i'm missing something obvious!

Thanks all
Joey

Comment: Can you post the actual error that you are getting?

Comment: can you check the same url using postman or some other tool whether you are getting 200 status @Joey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error should be clear in that you don't have a `view engine` set on your Express application when attempting to run the `render()` method.

From the Express documentation on template engines (obviously replace the below with the engine you're using in your application):

```
app.set('views', './views') // specify the views directory
app.set('view engine', 'ntl') // register the template engine
```

As for mocking the render method, you might want to take a look at https://github.com/danawoodman/sinon-express-mock for mocking your request and response objects in Express. Even if you don't want to use that package, you can peek at the source to see how they're doing it and if that matches what you're wanting to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your creating a brand new express app when you should instead be "requiring" an existing one used somewhere else in your real code. Your routes live inside that real express app so the only way to get to them is to test the real express app. In your current setup even if you solve the error by setting all the needed properties you still need to duplicate everything you put in the real express app.

**Remove from test.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
```

The code above is creating an empty app and thats not what you want to test.

**Replace it with**

```
 const app = require('../../../app').app //customize for your file system
```

The code above is an example but the idea is your `const app` under test needs to point to the instance of express in your real application. so if your main app file is server.js and its 3 levels up from your test file then in your route test you need to use

```
const app = require('../../../server.js).app
```

Assuming that insided server.js you called your express instance app.